# Add missing signature for info method in winston

Tags: typescript, winston, definitelytyped

I am creating a custom logger using winston in typescript. The `info` method is supposed to handle a single argument which is an object. Unfortunately, the types for winston in definitelyTyped don't provide this signature for `info`. So I tried to extend the interface to add the missing type. But it is not taken into account.

I get this error while compiling:

```
example.ts(23,13): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ bar: string; demo: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

The line 23 is the `logger.info(o)` line.

My source files:

`example.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="./expandWinston.d.ts"/>

import * as winston from "winston";

const logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      colorize: true,
      handleExceptions: true,
      humanReadableUnhandledException: true,
      json: false,
      prettyPrint: true,
      timestamp: true,
    }),
  ],
});

const o = {
  bar: "baz",
  demo: "foo",
};

logger.info(o);
```

`expandWinston.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace winston {
  export interface LoggerInstance {
    info(meta: any): LoggerInstance;
  }
}
```

**EDIT with solution:**

Final code in `expandWinston.d.ts`:

```
import { LoggerInstance } from "winston";

declare module "winston" {
  interface LeveledLogMethod {
    (meta: any): LoggerInstance;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that winston supports that?
Doesn't look like it from their github page, but I haven't looked that hard.

In any case, you can update the compiler like this:

```
declare module "winston" {
    interface LeveledLogMethod {
        (meta: any): LoggerInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me why I must use module instead of namespace there? And a string for winston?

Comment: It's called [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation), and you use a string for winston just like you import it (that way you're telling the compiler that they are the same). You're using a module instead of a namespace because winston is a module you import from, it's not a namespace